# Joining a table and a filtered table in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I have a one-to-many relationship between `Album` and `Song` classes. I would like to do some complex filtering on the albums and retrieve the corresponding songs.

Let's assume a fairly simple way to filter albums

```
filtered_albums = Album.where('released_on >= ?', from)
                       .where('rating > ?', rating)
                       .where(genre: genres)
```

Now, to retrieve the songs I'm currently using

```
Song.where(album_id: filtered_albums.pluck_id)
```

which produces the query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM songs 
WHERE album_id IN (1, 5, 34, 92, ..., 2392);
```

Since two queries are needed (one to extract the album ids, and the other to get songs) this could be very inefficient.

ActiveRecord allows to join tables, e.g. `Songs.joins(:albums)`, but I haven't found a way to do something like `Songs.joins(filtered_albums)`. Is there any other way to do the join without "plucking" the ids first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` to get the result you want.

```
Song.joins(:album).where('albums.released_on >= ?', from)
                   .where('albums.rating > ?', rating)
                   .where(albums: {genre: genres})
```

The `joins` method takes the association as an argument. I mean, whatever you pass in the joins method should be an association name defined in the model otherwise it will throw an error.

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the filter method in `Album` model itself, in other words you want to use scope in `joins`. Then you can do it as

```
Song.joins(:album).merge(Album.filtered_albums)
```

Moreover, you can defined filtered_albums as a named scope. So define it in Album model as:

```
scope :filtered_albums, ->(from, rating, genres){ where('released_on >= ?', from)
                   .where('rating > ?', rating).where(albums: {genre: genres}) }
```

Or define as a class method.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj. This works. I'd like to keep the album filtering in it's own class. Please see my comment on the post above.

Comment: You've made my day, thanks! The merge method is exactly what I was looking for :) In fact, it's one of the most underused ActiveRecord::Relation methods according to [this](http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/) post!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Song.joins(:albums).where('albums.released_on >= ?', from).where('albums.rating > ?', rating).where('albums.genre = ?', genres)
```

It makes only one query.

Comment: This works, thanks. My problem, however is that the filter method lives in the Album class (and takes lots of optional arguments which I don't specify here), and the songs finder lives in the Song class. So it's essentially the problem of joining an ActiveRecord::Relation object (filtered albums) and the songs table. Maybe it's the problem of my application design.